# is AnyLogic End of Task Preemption possible in version 8?

Tags: anylogic, preemption, event-simulation

I'm running a simulation model on AnyLogic.  I recently updated to version 8 University 8.4.0.  Before I that I had no problems running the simulation.  Now I get the following error after running the simulation for a short while:

`com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.ResourceUnitEndOfShiftTask cannot be cast to com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.ResourceUnitEntityServiceSubtask`

My intentional modelling choice is to have staff drop what they are doing when their shift ends.  Thus for the three resource pools in the model I have set the 'End of shift' may preempt field to True.  However, when I change these to false the model runs with no errors.  Is there a way to have End of task preemption in AnyLogic version 8?

I've tried google searching the error messages but don't get any relevant results.  I've also tried looking up ResourceUnitEndOfShiftTask and ResourceUnitEntityServiceSubtask in AnyLogic documentation but can't find any entries for them.

*Update: I contacted AnyLogic support (thanks to Felipe's Answer) and yup it's a known bug; changing the services to not preempt other tasks resolved the error for the time being although would have been an issue if I wanted tasks to be able to preempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen a few bugs from the AnyLogic Software that are still not solved in the last version related to preemption... For example there's an error when you try to terminate a shift through preemption, and there's nothing you can do about it...

Your best option is to contact AnyLogic support and send them the model in order to rule out a potential bug.

Answer (score 0):

If you updated from AL7, their process library was fundamentally different so it might not be compatible. Did you try to replace the current resource pool with the new object?

Your error indicates you are still using the old process library (the keyword "entity" gives it away). If it is not too much work, it might be easiest to just rebuild the blocks with the new library.

PS: There is no issues with AL8 resource pool "end of shift may preempt" functionality in general, works as always...

Comment: The new resource pool objects have the same names and fields as the original ones I was using;  I tried rebuilding from scratch using all new objects but am still getting the error. Are there other options for resource pool objects that I should be using in AL8?

Comment: suggest you send your nw model to AL support, might be a bug. Hard to say from here...